# XSLT parsing a string with both escaped and non escaped characters (< and &lt;)

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

In XSLT 1.0, what is the best way to process this xml element

```
<Product>This is a product. &lt; and its price is < 10</Product>
```

Notice that the 'less than sign' is represented twice. i.e. as `'&lt;' and '<'.`

To escape the `<` character i can do this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="html" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Product" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- If i set disable-output-escaping to "yes" the `<` character is shown correctly but the `"&lt;"` is completely stripped out.
- If i set disable-output-escaping to "no" the `<` character causes a parsing exception.

What can i do to allow both?

Comment: Only by magic, and rather black than white. Please use only well-formated XMLs.

Comment: What @kan is saying, is that `<` is not a valid text content in XML.

Comment: That XML is not valid (or even well-formed). XML *requires* that `<` be escaped as `&lt;` (or as `<![CDATA[<]]>` or `&#x3C;` or whatnot) inside parsed-character-data. (Unlike some SGML applications, XML doesn't have any concept of elements with pure character-data content.)

Comment: How do you want your output look like. Define input1 => output1 and input2 => output2

Comment: It's not an XML element, so you can't process it with XSLT.

Answer (score 3):

On the whole I think the best way to process your input in XSLT 1.0 is to use some other tool to turn your input into XML, and then process it normally. The behavior of XSLT processors when confronted with non-XML input tends to be erratic.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer (as others have alluded to but not directly said!) is that the input is not XML. XSLT simply won't work on that input - you will need to either pre-process it or else get whatever system is generating it fixed so that it generates actual XML rather than something that just *looks like* XML!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first approach (`disable-output-escaping="yes"`) is the only way. Otherwise you get an error, it's not possible to go that way.

You have to figure out how to prevent (or patch) the entity resolving (`&lt;` is resolved and replaced).

Comment: Presumably because the proposed solution doesn't work. disable-output-escaping doesn't magically enable you to parse ill-formed XML.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for the response, but there is a misunderstanding. The proposed solution was to patch the entity resolving, while using the `disable-output-escaping="yes"` directive. I know that OP should tidy the XML somehow, because that's an malformed XML, but if that's not possible, he could fix the XML with this workaround.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is any way to "patch entity resolving" in an XML parser to allow it to accept an unescaped `<` within the character content of an element.

Comment: @MichaelKay It depends on the implementation, I did it ~10 years ago with Xalan/Xerces, so it was possible. I'm not sure about the current implementations, though I think it should be possible.